# Centos/fedora/amazon linux: iptables best practice

Tags: centos, firewall, fedora, iptables, puppet

I tried to stick with one flavor of linux, but have somehow gotten into CentOs, Fedora and Amazon Linux mix. (Amazon linux is lowest priority as it has its own firewall thru console)

**Goal**: Configure firewall for CentOS and Fedora (15-17) using a common script (BASH or PUPPET)

**Confusion**:

1. Fedora 17 seems to use new "firewalld" for GUI which I dont care about. I just want to use a shell script.
2. If the server has both IPV4 and IPV6, will rules applied to IPV4 automatically apply to IPV6 too or do I have to run separate rules? I want them to be shared.
3. I downloaded the "puppetlabs-firewall" module - and it refers to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`  which I dont find in fedora. Also it only refers to RedHat|CentOs and not fedora:

   ```
   exec { "persist-firewall":
       command => $operatingsystem ? {
       "debian" => "/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4",
       /(RedHat|CentOS)/ => "/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables",
     }
     refreshonly => true,
   }
   Firewall {
     notify => Exec["persist-firewall"]
   }
   ```

I am open to using either puppet (will be preinstalled) or bash but **I just want a simple script that initializes a server with a master set of ports (maybe allowed IPs) that I provide**. If this works also for amazon linux, its a bonus.

Idempotent script would be best!

May seem quiet simple to some experts, but lot can go wrong with lot at stake for novices like me :)
 Thank you!

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

iptables is the userland interface to the Linux netfilter engine (IPv4)

ip6tables is the userland interface to the Linux netfilter engine (IPv6)

99% of the Linux firewalls are no more than wrappers arround iptables

/etc/sysconfig/iptables (in your example) is generated in the script by iptables-save

there are millions of iptables scripts in the net but it all depends on what you really need to do,
iptables is not just cut&paste